# Windows Azure Backup agent with Windows 7 pro

Tags: backup, azure

I know that windows azure backup is designed to work with windows server, but I have a small client that runs a little windows 7 pro machine as a "server/file share" in their office and I want to set up a simple back-up for them.  As I work with Azure in other ways with the client I would like to use azure for this solution as well.  Will windows azure backup agent work with windows 7 pro?  It would just be backing up some simple files/folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual Windows Azure Backup service is only available for 2012 Server or 2008 R2 sp1.

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh831419.aspx

I would suggest simply setting them up with one of the many SaaS offerings out there (backblaze, carbonite, crashplan, mozy, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Actually this has changed since december 2014.

Microsoft has annoucend that they now do support backing up Win7, Win8 and Win8.1.

Quote from azure.microsoft:

> We are excited to announce the support for backing up data to Azure
>   from Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 machines, using Azure
>   Backup. You can find more details on the supported client operating
>   system versions, SKUs in KB3015072. By downloading this update, you
>   automatically get all the capabilities released in the last few
>   months, including:
>
> ```
> KB2989574: Support for data sources more than 850GB
> KB2997692: Long Term Retention and Simplified Signup & Registration
> KB2999951: Support for Windows Server 2008
> KB3015072: Support for Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1
> ```
>
> This release opens up new scenarios for Azure Backup by enabling
>   customers to back up their on-premises files and folders directly to
>   Azure. Once the initial backup copy is completed, Azure Backup tracks
>   the changes to the backed up files and efficiently transfers only the
>   changed content over HTTPS.
>
> Setting up Azure Backup is really simple, and we have a 3 part video
>   series which explains the steps. The steps are detailed in a getting
>   started blog article as well.

Source: 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/16/azure-backup-announcing-support-for-windows-client-operating-system/